# Excel Summation of Multiple Conditional Maximum Values

Tags: excel, sumifs

I am working on getting pricing based on the number of units we are ordering using Excel sumifs. The data I have looks something like this:

```
A        B        C        D
Item1    Comp1    1        4.99
Item1    Comp1    10       3.99
Item1    Comp1    100      2.99
Item1    Comp2    1        13.99
Item1    Comp2    100      10.99
Item1    Comp3    1        2.99
Item1    Comp3    10       2.59
Item1    Comp3    50       2.19
Item1    Comp3    100      1.99
...      ...      ...      ...
```

Where column A is the main item, column B is the individual components of the item in column A, and column C is the number we need to order in order to get the price listed in column D.

In a separate sheet, I have the following table:

```
A        B        C
Item1    10       FORMULA
Item2    5        FORMULA
Item3    20       FORMULA
...      ...      ...
```

The point of this sheet is to have the Item name as seen in Column A of the first table, column B holds the number we need to order, and column C (hopefully) lists the total price by adding all the components at their respective price breaks.

In this example, the sum for Item1 I am looking for is 3.99 + 13.99 + 2.59 = 20.57 because 10 items gets the 10 price break for component 1, the 1 price break for component 2, and the 10 price break for component 3.

So far I am able to sum the cost based on the item name in column C:

```
=SUMIFS(Table1[D], Table1[A], "="A2)
```

I am having trouble starting the second part which is basically only summing the maximum price break for each component where Table1[C] <= B2.

Comment: So, for your example data, the correct result would be 4.99 + 13.99 + 2.99 or 21.97?

Comment: @StoneGiant Good point, I have updated my question to show the actual correct result would be 3.99 + 13.99 + 2.59 or 20.57

Comment: Do you have Office 365?